# PyQt4: set size of QGridLayout depending on size of QMainWindow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwidget

I'm writing a little Qt application with Python. I've created QMainWindow, which have a QGridLayout. In each grid I'm adding QTextBrowser Widget. I want left side of my grid to be not bigger than 25% of window. So I'll have two QTextBrowsers: one is 25% of window's width, and another is 75% of window's width. How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify relative width by giving each cell a stretch with [setStretch()](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qboxlayout.html#setStretch). They will get sizes proportional to the given stretches. Here is a simple example that makes the right widget 3 times greater than the left widget.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    Q = QtGui.QWidget()

    H = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    H.addWidget(QtGui.QTextBrowser())
    H.setStretch(0,1)
    H.addWidget(QtGui.QTextBrowser())
    H.setStretch(1,3)

    Q.setLayout(H)

    Q.show()

    app.exec_()
```

But, bear in mind that widgets have minimum sizes by default. So they can shrink below that. If you want to change that behavior also, consider setting minimum sizes to your liking.